# Deferred object confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following snippet works as expected:

```
function boxAnimation() {
        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        $('div').fadeIn('slow', dfd.resolve);            
        return dfd.promise();
    }

    $(function () {
        boxAnimation().done(
            function () { $(this).animate({ 'margin-top': 50 }); },
            function () { $(this).animate({ 'margin-left': 150 }); },
            function () { $(this).animate({ 'margin-top': 250 }); },
            function () { $(this).animate({ 'margin-left': 350 }); }
        ).fail(function () { alert('failed'); });
    });
```

However in this one **the differed object is neither rejected or resolved**.

Please tell me where am I going wrong.

```
function boxAnimation() {
        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
        $('div').fadeIn('slow', function () {
            if (randomNum == 1) {
                dfd.reject;
            }
            else {
                dfd.resolve;
            }
        });            
        return dfd.promise();
    }

    $(function () {
        boxAnimation().done(
            function () { $(this).animate({ 'margin-top': 50 }); },
            function () { $(this).animate({ 'margin-left': 150 }); },
            function () { $(this).animate({ 'margin-top': 250 }); },
            function () { $(this).animate({ 'margin-left': 350 }); }
        ).fail(function () { alert('failed'); });
    });
```

my body is:

```
<div id='box' style='width:200px; height:200px; border:solid 1px #222222; display:none; background:#cccccc'></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call functions; currently you're accessing them and leaving them untouched. By actually calling `reject`/`resolve`, you are really rejecting/resolving things.

In the `fadeIn` in the first example, you passed it without `()`. This is correct, because you should *leave it untouched* at that point. jQuery will internally call the function when the animation is done.

Since in the second example the calls are already in a function that is executed when the animation is done, you should *call* them at that point.

```
if (randomNum == 1) {
    dfd.reject();      // '()' calls a function
}
else {
    dfd.resolve();
}
```

---

Secondly, inside a `done` handler, `this` is the `Deferred` object. If you want to pass the `div`, you can do so by passing it when rejecting/resolving: http://jsfiddle.net/PrmQR/1/.

```
function boxAnimation() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    $('div').fadeIn('slow', function () {
        if (randomNum == 1) {
            dfd.reject(this);    // pass div
        }
        else {
            dfd.resolve(this);
        }
    });            
    return dfd.promise();
}

$(function () {
    boxAnimation().done(
        function (x) { $(x).animate({ 'margin-top': 50 }); },     // x is the div
        function (x) { $(x).animate({ 'margin-left': 150 }); },
        function (x) { $(x).animate({ 'margin-top': 250 }); },
        function (x) { $(x).animate({ 'margin-left': 350 }); }
    ).fail(function () { alert('failed'); });
});
```

Comment: That makes sense however and I tried it before but this causes an error (Chrome: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined) and fbug: a.ownerDocument is undefined. Did you get it to work by only turning them to functions?

Comment: @XGreen: I think your DOM is involved somehow but I don't know what your HTML looks like. It seems like you're using the minified version; using the unminified version of jQuery helps a lot when debugging.

Comment: @XGreen: I missed something. You're expecting `this` to be the `div`, but it's the `Deferred` object. You should pass `this` when rejecting/resolving like this: http://jsfiddle.net/PrmQR/.

Comment: Thank you for rescuing my boxed head